# How to programmatically generate a link in MediaWiki to a page via php?

Tags: php, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I just want to generate a Link to a page of a MediaWiki **in CODE via PHP**, specifically in the skin template.

The background is that the skin has a set of links in a sidebar that don't change but refer to a page in the Wiki.

I don't want to use hard coded links as Host-URLs might change and I don't want to deal with GET-parameters in the URL that might already be there.

Any ideas?

I can't find a solution in the MediaWiki Docs, API etc.

Comment: I don't get it -- why can't you just use `MediaWiki:Sidebar` to add your links to the sidebar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$title = Title::newFromText( 'Pagename' );
echo $title->getLocalUrl();
```

/wiki/Pagename

```
echo $title->getFullURL();
```

http://example.com/wiki/Pagename

```
echo $title->getFullURL( array( 'foo' => 'bar' ) );
```

http://example.com/w/index.php?title=Pagename&foo=bar